# Trying to get a picture ID to get home

Tags: identification

There is an American in Manchester that has been stuck there for almost a year. He lives in the U.S. He has no proof of ID with him. What does he need to do to get a picture ID so he can get a plane ticket home?

Comment: What is his nationality?

Comment: American. Born in Ohio

Comment: @S Potts What ID did he use to enter the UK? Has he contacted a US embassy in the UK for advice?

Comment: And please do not just answer in comments - update your question.

Comment: Has this American asked you for any money?

Answer (score 4):

He should contact his embassy for a passport or an emergency passport.  In the case of an American citizen, that would be:

> https://uk.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/u-s-passports/